# Efficient way to init state storage of forms

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm working on a quite comprehensive form and was wondering if there is a smart way to prevent me of doing the following state initialisation:

```
class Demo extends React.Component {



  state = { firstName = "",
            secondName = "" };
           //and so on...

  render() {
    const { firstName, secondName } = this.state;
    //and so on

    return (
      <div>
        <Form>
          <Form.Input
            placeholder="Name"
            name="name"
            value={firstName}
          />
         //and so on
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If I don't init the state with empty strings I get the following Warning:

> Component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be
>   controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to
>   controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

What's the state of the art way to deal with this?
Thanks!
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

If you are using value as your state value then it will be `undefined` in render method in case you don't initialize state. So it is recommended to initialize your state like you're doing because you have controlled inputs. I believe this would help your case

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work but problem is you need input handlers for each fields which is cumbersome if you have huge form.

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: '',
        submitted: false
    };
   }

   handleFirstName = (e) => {
         this.setState({firstName: e.target.value});
   }

   handleLastName = (e) => {
         this.setState({lastName: e.target.value});
   }
   handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const payload = [{this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName}];
        this.props.saveData(payload);
   }

   render() {
    return(
        <form>
            <label>
                Firstname:
                <input type="text" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleFirstName} />
            </label>

              <label>
                Lastname:
                <input type="text" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleLastName} />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
        </form>          
    );
  }
}
```

Better solution for handling form is using lib like [react-final-form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form)

Comment: thanks, but i don't think you need individual handles. ... that's even complex.
simplification: 


    `handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value }); `